# Spark Cannot call a function form .Withcolumn

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I Have a schema like below, which is an output of `collect_list` of a `groupby`

```
root
|
|-- usedServiceUnits: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- accumulators: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

**Values in this looks like below**

```
+----------------+
|usedServiceUnits|
+----------------+
|[180, 180, 1]   |==> this is an array of String
|[180, 180, 1]   |
+----------------+
```

I have to call a `def` over this field like

```
abc.select("serviceId", "recordId", "usedServiceUnits")
.withColumn("usedServiceUnits1",lit(sumAllValuesinString($"usedServiceUnits"))

def sumAllValuesinString(inString: String): String= {
 var sum = 0
 val DELIM =','
 val a = splitString(inString,DELIM)
 for ( x <- a){
   sum += Integer.parseInt(x)
 }
 sum.toString()
```

}

How can I call this function and get sum as return and set to my new column - usedServiceUnits1. I have similar kind of calculation required for some more fields where functions are different. So basically I am looking for how to pass this to my functions or Where to change?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for Array of String, using an `UDF` as per your question

```
val getSumOf = udf((value : Seq[String]) => value.map(_.toInt).sum.toString) 
abc.withColumn("usedServiceUnits1",udf(getSumOf($"usedServiceUnits"))
```

Hope this will be effective for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your requirement, I would suggest you to use `udf` function

Define `udf` function as

```
def sumAllValuesinString = udf((inString: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
  var sum = 0
  val DELIM =','
  for ( x <- inString){
    sum += Integer.parseInt(x)
  }
  sum.toString()
})
```

And then call the `udf` function using `withColumn` as

```
abc.withColumn("usedServiceUnits1", sumAllValuesinString($"usedServiceUnits"))
```

I hope this is what you require